# In asp.net MVC Telerik grid, How to change background color of selected row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

In asp.net MVC Telerik grid, How to change background color of selected row, as Im using ActionLink inside the grid, my default color of selection is blue and the Link color is also blue, so when I select any row the links are not visible

Below is my Code

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Aspectek.MBI.Entities.Products.Product>()
            .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {            
            columns.Bound(e => e.SKU).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(120);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Barcode).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(120);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ProductName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(120);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Category.CategoryName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.UI("CategoryFilter")).Width(120);
            columns.Bound(o => o.SubCategory.SubCategoryName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.UI("SubCategoryFilter")).Width(120);           

            columns.Bound(o => o.IsActive).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(120);
            columns.Template(@<text> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Product", new { id = item.Id, @style = "text-transform:capitalize;" }) </text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='/Products/Product/Edit/#= Id#'>View/Edit</a>").Width(100); 
            columns.Template(@<text> @Html.ActionLink("Duplicate", "Product", new { id = item.Id }) </text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='/Products/Product/CopyProduct/#= Id#'>CopyProduct</a>").Width(100);
            columns.Template(@<text> @Html.ActionLink("ExportHTML", "Product", new { id = item.Id }) </text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='/Products/Product/ExportHTML/#= Id#'>ExportHTML</a>").Width(100);
            columns.Template(@<text> @Html.ActionLink("SendEmail", "Product", new { id = item.Id }) </text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='/Products/Product/SendEmail/#= Id#'>SendEmail</a>").Width(100);
                        columns.Command(c =>
            {
                c.Custom("DeleteRecord").Text("Delete").Click("onClick");
            });
        })
.Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onDataBound"))
.ToolBar(toolBar => toolbar
.Custom()
.Text("Export To CSV")
.HtmlAttributes(new { id = "export" })
.Url(Url.Action("ProductExportToCSVFile", "Product", new { page = 1, pageSize = "20" )))
.ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
.Excel(excel => excel
.FileName("MBI Products Export.xlsx").Filterable(true)
.ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Product"))).ToolBar(tools => tools.Pdf()).Pdf(pdf => pdf
.FileName("MBI Products Export.pdf")
.ProxyURL(Url.Action("Pdf_Export_Save", "Grid")))
.Sortable()
.Pageable()
.Scrollable()
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
.Reorderable(reorderable => reorderable.Columns(true))
.Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))
.ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
.Selectable(selectable => selectable
.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
.Extra(false)
.Operators(operators =>
.ForString(str => str.Clear()
.StartsWith("Starts with")
.Contains("Contains")
.IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
.IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to"))))
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:500px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
.PageSize(10)
.ServerOperation(false)
.Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Product"))
.Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
.Destroy(update => update.Action("DeleteProduct", "Product"))
))
```

Comment: Default color is actually orange.

Comment: Hi Pluc, Actually in my application the color is in blue, and Im not able to figure out how to change the theme, any knowledge on this ?

Comment: You choose the theme by choosing which .css file you include. The common will always be there, but the 2nd .css is the theme. If you use "kendo.default.css", the default "highlight" color will be orange. You can build your own theme with the theme builder (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/themebuilder). If your color change is global, you might want to look into that. You can also change the theme at runtime but I never looked into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guessing this is because of theme you have selected?  But you can override the background color fairly easily with plain old css.

This example sets the selected row color to grey with white text

```
<style type="text/css">
    .k-state-selected  {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #dcdcdc;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Joe, How to use this CSS in @Html.ActionLink

Comment: @sandeepduddu I added this to the top of the page with my kendo grid.

Comment: could you post the line of code here. I cant find it at top of the page.